# SpringBoot JUnit test says Field required a bean of type 'com.labprog.egressos.service.ContatoService' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-test

I made the first endpoint class of my SpringBoot project, then tried to test it with JUnit, using @WebMvcTest and mocks. When I run the test it fails to load ApplicationContext because of the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field contatoService in com.labprog.egressos.controller.EgressoController required a bean of type 'com.labprog.egressos.service.ContatoService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.labprog.egressos.service.ContatoService' in your configuration.

2022-06-12 11:55:30.365 ERROR 23962 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@7139992f] to prepare test instance [com.labprog.egressos.controller.EgressoControllerTest@3df1a1ac]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    ...
```

My project's file structure is this:

```
.
├── controller
│   └── EgressoController.java
├── EgressosApplication.java
├── model
│   ├── Cargo.java
│   ├── Contato.java
│   ├── CursoEgresso.java
│   ├── CursoEgressoPK.java
│   ├── Curso.java
│   ├── Depoimento.java
│   ├── dto
│   │   ├── ContatoDTO.java
│   │   └── EgressoDTO.java
│   ├── Egresso.java
│   ├── FaixaSalario.java
│   ├── ProfEgresso.java
│   └── repository
│       ├── CargoRepo.java
│       ├── ContatoRepo.java
│       ├── CursoEgressoRepo.java
│       ├── CursoRepo.java
│       ├── DepoimentoRepo.java
│       ├── EgressoRepo.java
│       ├── FaixaSalarioRepo.java
│       └── ProfEgressoRepo.java
└── service
    ├── CargoService.java
    ├── ContatoService.java
    ├── CursoEgressoService.java
    ├── CursoService.java
    ├── DepoimentoService.java
    ├── EgressoService.java
    ├── exceptions
    │   ├── RegraNegocioRunTime.java
    │   └── ServiceRuntimeException.java
    └── FaixaSalarioService.java
```

My EgressoController.java class:

```
package com.labprog.egressos.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.labprog.egressos.service.ContatoService;
import com.labprog.egressos.service.CursoService;
import com.labprog.egressos.service.EgressoService;
import com.labprog.egressos.service.exceptions.ServiceRuntimeException;
import com.labprog.egressos.model.Contato;
import com.labprog.egressos.model.Egresso;
import com.labprog.egressos.model.dto.ContatoDTO;
import com.labprog.egressos.model.dto.EgressoDTO;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/egressos")
public class EgressoController {
    @Autowired
    private EgressoService service;
    
    @Autowired
    private ContatoService contatoService;

    @PostMapping("/salvar")
    public ResponseEntity salvar(@RequestBody EgressoDTO dto) {
        Egresso egresso = Egresso.builder()
                .nome(dto.getNome())
                .email(dto.getEmail())
                .cpf(dto.getCpf())
                .resumo(dto.getResumo())
                .urlFoto(dto.getUrlFoto())
                .build();
        try {
            Egresso salvo = service.salvar(egresso);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(salvo);
        } catch (ServiceRuntimeException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @PutMapping("/atualizar/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity atualizar(
            @RequestBody EgressoDTO dto,
            @PathVariable Long id) {
        Egresso egresso = Egresso.builder()
                .id(id)
                .nome(dto.getNome())
                .email(dto.getEmail())
                .cpf(dto.getCpf())
                .resumo(dto.getResumo())
                .urlFoto(dto.getUrlFoto())
                .build();
        try {
            Egresso salvo = service.atualizar(egresso);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(salvo);
        } catch (ServiceRuntimeException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @PutMapping("/atualizar_contatos/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity atualizarContatos(
            @RequestBody EgressoDTO dto,
            @PathVariable Long id) {
        Egresso egresso = Egresso.builder()
                .id(id)
                .nome(dto.getNome())
                .email(dto.getEmail())
                .cpf(dto.getCpf())
                .resumo(dto.getResumo())
                .urlFoto(dto.getUrlFoto())
                .build();
        ArrayList<Contato> contatos = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ContatoDTO contatoDto : dto.getContatos()) {
            Contato contato = Contato.builder()
                    .id(contatoDto.getId())
                    .nome(contatoDto.getNome())
                    .urlLogo(contatoDto.getUrlLogo())
                    .build();
            contatos.add(contato);
        }
        ArrayList<Contato> contatosValidados = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            for (Contato contato : contatos) {
                if(contato.getId() == null) {
                    contatosValidados.add(contatoService.salvar(contato));
                } else {
                    contatosValidados.add(contatoService.atualizar(contato));
                }
            }
        } catch (ServiceRuntimeException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            Egresso salvo = service.atualizarContatos(egresso, contatosValidados);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(salvo);
        } catch (ServiceRuntimeException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/remover/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity remover(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Egresso egresso = Egresso.builder()
                .id(id)
                .build();
        try {
            service.remover(egresso);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).build();
        } catch (ServiceRuntimeException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/buscar/{email}")
    public ResponseEntity buscar(@PathVariable String email) {
        Egresso filtro = Egresso.builder()
                .email(email)
                .build();
        try {
            Egresso egresso = service.buscar(filtro).get(0);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(egresso);
        } catch (ServiceRuntimeException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

My ContatoService.java class:

```
package com.labprog.egressos.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.labprog.egressos.model.Contato;
import com.labprog.egressos.model.repository.ContatoRepo;
import com.labprog.egressos.service.exceptions.ServiceRuntimeException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Example;
import org.springframework.data.domain.ExampleMatcher;
import org.springframework.data.domain.ExampleMatcher.StringMatcher;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class ContatoService {
    
    @Autowired 
    private ContatoRepo repo;

    @Transactional
    public Contato salvar(Contato contato) {
        verificarContato(contato);
        return repo.save(contato);
    }

    @Transactional
    public Contato atualizar(Contato contato) {
        verificarContato(contato);
        verificarId(contato);
        return repo.save(contato);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void remover(Contato contato) {
        verificarId(contato);
        repo.delete(contato);
    }

    public List<Contato> buscar(Contato filtro) {
        Example<Contato> example =
                Example.of(filtro, ExampleMatcher.matching()
                        .withIgnoreCase()
                        .withStringMatcher(StringMatcher.CONTAINING)
                );

        return repo.findAll(example);
    }

    private void verificarContato(Contato contato) {
        if (contato == null)
            throw new ServiceRuntimeException("O contato está nulo");                
        if ((contato.getNome() == null) || (contato.getNome().equals("")))
            throw new ServiceRuntimeException("Nome do contato deve ser informado");                   
    }

    private void verificarId(Contato contato) {
        if ((contato == null) || (contato.getId() == null)) {
            throw new ServiceRuntimeException("ID de contato inválido");
        }
    }

}
```

My EgressoControllerTest.java class:

```
package com.labprog.egressos.controller;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.labprog.egressos.model.Egresso;
import com.labprog.egressos.model.dto.EgressoDTO;
import com.labprog.egressos.service.EgressoService;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest (controllers =  EgressoController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class EgressoControllerTest {
    
    static final String API = "/api/egressos";

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    EgressoService service;

    @Test
    public void deveSalvarEgresso() throws Exception {
        // Cenário
        EgressoDTO dto = EgressoDTO.builder()
                .nome("Nome")
                .email("email@e.com")
                .cpf("123456789")
                .resumo("Resumo")
                .urlFoto("urlFoto")
                .build();

        Egresso egresso = Egresso.builder()
                .id(1l)
                .nome(dto.getNome())
                .email(dto.getEmail())
                .cpf(dto.getCpf())
                .resumo(dto.getResumo())
                .urlFoto(dto.getUrlFoto())
                .build();

        Mockito.when(service.salvar(
            Mockito.any(Egresso.class))).thenReturn(egresso);

        String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(dto);

        // Ação
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = 
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(API + "/salvar")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(json);

        // Verificação
        mvc.perform(request)
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isCreated());
    }

}
```

And my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.labprog</groupId>
    <artifactId>egressos</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>egressos</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I need the ContatoService instance for my atualizarContatos() method (update Egresso's list of Contact). It's odd that the autowired EgressoService works as supposed, and if I run the test commenting contatoService and atualizarContatos(), the test works. Whatever other service class I include as @Autowired in my controller, it yields that error.

It confuses me, as if I run the application and try to use the endpoint for atualizarContatos() in Insomnia, it works just fine:
[image: Insomnia using the endpoint atualizarContatos()]

My services and models are covered with tests already. Why can't the controller test inject the dependencies correctly?

I'm working in Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS with Java 18.

Comment: Define the ContatoService inside your test class like below: @MockBean
    ContatoService service, you only defined the instance for EgressoService

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in our API Gateway unit tests.

what worked for me is adding the bean to the unit test as:

```
@MockBean
private AuthRestClient mockClient;
```

full:

```
here are my imports etc:

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import com.xxx.yyyy.core.interfaces.constants.AuthorityConstants;
import com.xxx.yyy.core.interfaces.ws.AuthRestClient;


@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles(value = "test")
@WithMockUser(username = "admin", roles = { AuthorityConstants.PRIV_USERADMIN })
class XxxServicesApiGatewayApplicationTests {

    @MockBean
    private AuthRestClient mockClient;

    @Test
    void test() {

        // assertions, etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Is not work, now says `Cannot mock/spy class org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc`

Comment: it could be that you're using the wrong imports...  API Gateway uses the reactive web "stuff".  I've updated my answer to include the whole test code.

Comment: also, I don't think Gateway has the MVC stuff.

ex: 
```
@WebMvcTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```